# Site.UrlRewriter and Wildcards

Tags: apex, angular, urlrewriter, angularjs

I'm attempting to use Angular Routing to handle all of my public facing pages. It creates a pretty smooth experience for the customers, and I have gotten it working on my development machine, but now, moving it to production, I have to direct any URL requests from the SalesForce Site to go to the main "/" page to have the routing handled by angular.

Everything works properly when I go to my main page,  then select links from there. The issue is when I try to directly link to an internal page (which is common in this application). Right now, I get a 404, because the VisualForce "server" is trying to fulfill a link request that only my angular app knows about.

Is there any way to use wildcards in

`apex
global class kbUrlControl implements Site.UrlRewriter {
    global PageReference mapRequestUrl (PageReference 
        )
     global PageReference[] generateUrlFor(PageReference[]
        )
}`

I basically just need to send all Urls to "/' - Just not sure how to do it.

Explicitly naming all Urls to redirect isn't going to be feasible, I have over 40k of them to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for this is to make the index page of the angular app the "default template" for the site. This will enable you to use Angular's routing capabilities.